# minimum time between signals in bash

Tags: linux, bash, signals, hostapd, bash-trap

I'm trying to make a bash script that launches / stops an access point using hostapd.

We have a corner case where we want to switch to another wifi channel as fast as possible, and as hostapd doesn't have support for channel swapping on the fly, we have to:

- kill the process
- change the config file
- start hostapd again.

I decided to send signals from the main app to this script (USR1 and USR2) to do this, but I don't get the result I expected. I always receive the second signal in first place, so it doesn't work. I have tried to add a sleep(1) in the code to make this work, but it's not an elegant solution.

Here are the c++ lines i'm using,

```
killAP();
sleep(1);
generateAP();
```

and this is the script.

```
#!/bin/ash

TASKS=''

enqueueLaunch () {
    TASKS="$TASKS launch"
}

enqueueKill () {
   TASKS="$TASKS kill"
}

launchAP ()  {
    logger -t LAUNCH Launching AP--.
    /scripts/launchAP
    logger -t LAUNCH DONE
}

killAP () {
    logger -t KILL Killing AP

    PID=`cat /var/run/wifi-phy0.pid`
    kill -9 $PID
    iw wlan0 del
    rm -f /var/run/wifi-phy0.pid
    logger -t KILL  DONE
}

parse () {
    for i in $@ ; do
        case "$i" in
            "launch")
                launchAP
                ;;
            "kill")
                killAP
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

echo $$ > /var/run/hostapd-sh.pid

trap enqueueLaunch SIGUSR1
trap enqueueKill SIGUSR2

while :
do                            
   if [ ! -z "$TASKS" ] ; then
      parse $TASKS
      TASKS=""                      
   fi           
   sleep 1      
done
```

Any idea is welcomed.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why does this script run in the background listening for signals instead of being invoked when needed?

Comment: We are using fastCGI in the app and if we stop & start hostapd after opening fascgi sockets, hostapd keeps open and it acquires those sockets making issues when i try to bind them again.

Comment: While real-time signals are guaranteed to be delivered in the order that they were sent, the delivery order of standard signals is unspecified. Try switching to real-time signals.

Comment: @Acampoh, have you tried switching to real-time signals?

Answer (score 0):

While real-time signals are guaranteed to be delivered in the order that they were sent, the delivery order of standard signals is unspecified. Try switching to real-time signals.

---

Also, you may want to try a different approach altogether. As its [man page specifies](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/hostapd.8.html), instead of killing and then relaunching *hostapd*, you can simply ask it to reload its configuration file:

> Changes to the configuration file can be reloaded by sending a *SIGHUP* to the hostapd processor or with the [*hostapd_cli*(8)](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/hostapd_cli.8.html) utility, using `hostapd_cli reconfigure`.

Note that established connections are lost on configuration reload.

Comment: I have tried that. It seemed to work, but the AP was completely unresponsive. It was impossible to connect to it. Maybe there was another reason for that, but no idea. I have also seen this thread 

http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2011-January/022394.html

I suppose it's too old, but i haven't seen anywhere else somebody saying that it's supported right now.

Comment: Is the AP unresponsive also when the configuration is reloaded but the channel remains unmodified?